# Stop Load data from .json if when data already load

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

I have 2 fragment( Fragment A and fragment B) with functions to load data using .json.

When I click fragment A, the data will load, and when I click fragment B the data will load too.

When I click fragment A another time, the data is reloaded and duplicated (appended with the data from the first click).

How to stop loading data if data is already loaded?

example image [image: duplicate]
here my fragment code

fragment_a.java

```
public class fragment_a extends Fragment {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MovieFragment1.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://.......";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public MovieFragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();


        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                if (obj.getString("tipe").equals("chest")){
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("images1"));
                                //movie.setDescribe(obj.getString("describe"));
                                //movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                //        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("id"));
                                movie.setTipe(obj.getString("tipe"));

                                /*// Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

fragment_b.java

```
public class fragment_b extends Fragment {
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MovieFragment1.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://......";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;

    public MovieFragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        hidePDialog();
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();


        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                if (obj.getString("tipe").equals("forearm")){
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("name"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("images1"));
                                //movie.setDescribe(obj.getString("describe"));
                                //movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                //        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("id"));
                                movie.setTipe(obj.getString("tipe"));

                                /*// Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);*/

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);
                            }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

tabfragment.java (fragment adapter)

```
public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 3 ;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
         */
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,null);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**
         *Set an Apater for the View Pager
         */
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        /**
         * Now , this is a workaround ,
         * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
         * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
         */

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return x;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 : return new fragment_a();
                case 1 : return new HomeFragment();
                case 2 : return new fragment_b();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    return "Chest";
                case 1 :
                    return "Movie";
                case 2 :
                    return "Forearm";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where you are storing data. At activity level or fragment level. If you are storing at activity level then simple null check will be sufficient.

Comment: @nilkash storing data on moviefragment.javathen its fragment, can you give me example?

Comment: Clear your movieList of fragment_b inside onResponse

Comment: @RakshitNawani where im must put it movieList.clear();?

Comment: @F_X : just inside your try of onResponse write movieList.clear(); it will work for you

Comment: @RakshitNawani im try input movieList.clear(); under Try , but in fragment_a only load 1 list and on fagment_b not load anything

Comment: @F_X : Sorry above your for loop it will work like a charm sorry for the above comment

Comment: @RakshitNawani Thanks, its works :) , but any other ways not always load data from internet? like when first time open fragment load data then when second time open fragment no need load data again because data already load,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap your `movieRequest` with

```
if(movieList.isEmpty()){
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, ... ETC...
    // etc
}
```

But remember that with this approach your data will not update if it is changed on server, to make it updatable you must clear `movieList` before filling it every time instead:

```
movieList.clear();
```

Comment: You can put it inside onRequest or before creating JsonArray, just do it before you add data to list

Comment: Thanks for your help btw,
but i have a nother problem, when the first click fragment data will load, but when second click in the same fragment when data already load so no need load data again, can you help for this?

Comment: When you want data to update? If you want it to update only on first load you can go with `if(movieList.isEmpty())`, but I have already mentioned that if data will update in this time you will not see this changes before you restart Activity. Another approach is to use some hashing mechanism to check if it is up to date, or some data changed timestamp on server, but it is harder to implement. It depends on how many data you have, how early it updates and also is it critical for user to see up to date data.

Comment: actually im only want all data will update every they firsttime open the apps, yes im try your code ` if(movieList.isEmpty())` but when second time click same fragment `pDialog` loading always shown up and need click to hide `pDialog`, how to solved this `pDialog`?

Comment: call `hidePDialog();` in `else` statement, try to understand your code its easier than you think :)

Comment: yes im using that code, the problem is i forget about another fragment lol , sorry im to dumb for details :D thanks for your help :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110215/discussion-between-f-x-and-murat-mustafin).